# Recursive Coin Change Function Prints Correct Answer but Doesn't Return It

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

With my function below, it prints the correct answer to the problem in the base case conditional, but it won't return it. My output prints from the base case in the function on the 1st line, then prints the returned value from the function on the second line.

If I return the value of the recursive call, then the base case isn't reached.

**I see this output:**

[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

None

**But I expect this output:**

[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

```
def changeslow(amounts, goal, coins = [], highest = 0, sum = 0, results = []):
    # Base case
    if sum == goal:
        result = [] 
        if highest == amounts[(len(amounts)-1)]:
            result = []
            for amount in amounts:
                count = coins.count(amount)
                result.append(count)
                count = count + 1 
            print result
        return result

    # Recursive case
    for value in amounts:
        if value >= highest:
            copy = coins[:]
            copy.append(value)
            if sum + value <= goal:
                changeslow(amounts, goal, copy, value, sum + value, results)


amounts = [1, 5, 10, 25, 50]

print(changeslow(amounts, 51))
```

Comment: The recursive case should also use the return statement.

Comment: If I add a return statement before the recursive call, nothing is returned and the base case isn't reached. The output = None